# Update embedded collection element MongoDB

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

We have the next domain model:

```
public class User
{
    public ObjectId Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public List<Comment> Comments { get; set; }
}

public class Comment
{
    public ObjectId Id { get; set; }

    public string Text { get; set; }
}
```

We use MongoDB CSharp driver in our project.
We have collection "Users" and all comments that relate to specific user, we store within this single document.

**Question 1:** What is the correct way to update comment text when I know **UserId** and **CommentId**?
**Question 2:** Should embeded elements have own identifiers?

Thanks

Comment: To answer Question 2 it would be helpful to know more about your use case. Will you often need to refer to comments outside of the context of the user they relate to?

Typically if you are embedding them, you wouldn't also give each comment its own unique identifier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the code you need:

```
var update = Update.Set("Comments.$.Text", "new comment text");
var query = Query.And(
   Query<User>.EQ(u => u.Id, userId),
   Query<User>.ElemMatch(u => u.Comments, eq => eq.EQ(c => c.Id, commentId)));
userCollection.Update(query, update);
```